# 2 Dimensional target variable from a CNN

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, keras-layer, yolo

I am tring to build an object detection model with only 3 classes. Input is images with shape **(64,28,28,3)** and the output shape is **(64,9,8)** and the sample of output variable is:

```
array([[0.24, 0.06, 0.56, 0.44, 1.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.31, 0.54, 0.56, 0.44, 1.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.21, 0.18, 0.54, 0.44, 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

The image is divided into 9 grids so 9 rows. The first 4 values of each rows are the co-ordinates of the box created for the object, 5th value is a flag 0/1. If no object present in the particular grid than 0 or else 1, 6-8 is the class value as there is only 3 classes.

I am using keras framework. I have tried some code need some help to modify as needed:

```
x = Flatten()(vgg.output)
x1 = Dense(4,activation='sigmoid')(x)
x2 = Dense(1,activation='softmax')(x)
x3 = Dense(3,activation='sigmoid')(x)
y = Concatenate()([x1,x2,x3])
model = Model(vgg.input,y)
```

My question is how I can build the last layer of CNN. Till now I have worked only on classification problem which is 1D output. Any help will be appreciated.